# Site Content type MS word

Tags: content-type, word, quick-parts

I have a new word template that contains a new quick part that references to Sharepoint metadata.  I have about 1000 documents that need to have this new template applied to it so that the new quick part info is visible.  Is there any way to update the documents with the new template with losing the content of the document?

Comment: when you say a new word template, do you mean change the documents content type? if so any fields that remain the same should not be erased. If the fields changed but you still want the data you will need a PowerShell script to get each document, save current document fields in variables, change the ContentType, save the variables to the new fields. Move to Next doucment

Comment: Yes I believe we are talking about the same thing.  I'm hoping that there is a powershell script some where that can do this for me as my powershell are non existent.

Comment: Write both your Content types above, with each field listed and I can probably put something together to at least get you started